Link between homeomorphism and empty interior
I consider a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ and an homeomorphism $g : X\to Y\subset\mathbb{R}^d$. I woul like to prove that if $Y$ has non empty interior (for the topology of $\mathbb{R}^d$) then $X$ also.
My attempt was the following : let $U$ ben an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $U\subset Y$, we have that $g^{-1}(U)$  is open in $X$ since $g$ is an homeomorphism, however I do not see why it should be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
If you have counter example to propose I would be glad to see it please.

This is just invariance of domain

Thank you a lot. Yes, however it seems that the result is not trivial at all, do you know any more easier argument for this ?

Not really. Its just something that doesn't have a known elementary proof and every proof goes through some non-trivial theory

I see, thank you for this information !

This follows by applying invariance of domain to the inverse of $g$. In fact, you don't need to assume that $g$ is a homeomorphism: it suffices to assume that it is bijective and open (so that its inverse is continuous).

Thank you a lot !
